# How can I stop (or understand why) a property binding is being coerced?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, telerik-radbutton

I have a group of buttons that are created based on a collection as below:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5" MinHeight="30">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}" AlternationCount="{Binding Filters.Count}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <telerik:RadToggleButton Content="{Binding Path=Text}" Margin="0,5,10,5" Padding="10,5" MinWidth="40" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                                           IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" />
                  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,15,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
          </StackPanel>
```

With the `Filters` collection looking like:

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemFilter> _Filters;
public ObservableCollection<Filter> Filters
{
  get
  {
    if (_Filters == null)
    {
      _Filters = new ObservableCollection<ItemFilter>
      {
        new ItemFilter { Text = "A", Selected = true, Command = Commands.FilterA },
        new ItemFilter { Text = "B", Selected = false, Command = Commands.FilterB },
        new ItemFilter { Text = "C", Selected = false, Command = Commands.FilterC },
        new ItemFilter { Text = "D", Selected = false, Command = Commands.FilterD },
        new ItemFilter { Text = "E", Selected = false, Command = Commands.FilterE },
        new ItemFilter { Text = "F", Selected = false, Command = Commands.FilterF, Enabled = false },
        new ItemFilter { Text = "G", Selected = false, Command = Commands.FilterG, Enabled = false },
      };
    }

    return _Filters;
  }
}
```

ItemFilter class is pretty simple:

```
   public sealed class ItemFilter : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public RoutedCommand Command { get; set; }

    private bool _Selected;

    public bool Selected
    {
      get { return _Selected; }
      set
      {
        _Selected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
      }
    }

    private bool _Enabled;

    public bool Enabled
    {
      get { return _Enabled; }
      set
      {
        _Enabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Enabled"));
      }
    }

    public ItemFilter()
    {
      _Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
  }
```

There is also some other logic that manages the `Selected` state based on some business rules when each filter button is clicked. Currently nothing modifies the `Enabled` property on the `ItemFilter` collection objects after it is set on creation.

The issue is that, regardless of what I set as the command, the button text, the enabled property, the selected property or the position of the button in the collection, it always ends up as `Enabled = false` - and only for this button, all other behave as expected.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried removing the command attribute and binding from the items controls XAML and the button enablement is as expected.

Also changing the binding mode of the command to `OneWayToSource` also shows the button enablement correctly but the command binding doesn't work as expected.

**UPDATE**

The related `Command` code looks like this

```
 public static class Commands
 {
    // all commands for this example follow this pattern
    public static readonly RoutedCommand FilterF = new RoutedCommand("f", typeof(Commands));
 }
```

Comment: It has to do with _Commands.FilterF_. What is the related code?

Comment: See second update for `Command` code.